# What's the difference between WordPress random_int() and PHP built-in function random_int()?

Tags: functions

What's the difference between WordPress defined function [`random_int()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/random_int/) and PHP built-in function [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)?

Also, if there is a difference, how does the PHP interpreter understand which of the two functions I'm calling?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WordPress is old. In fact, it is older than PHP7, in which PHP introduced [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php). WP wanted/needed this functionality before, so another method was implemented.

> how does the PHP interpreter understand which of the two functions I'm calling?

Good question. The interpreter doesn't understand this. And hence, if you had PHP7 and would define this function new, you would get an error. This is why. the file with the function definition is only loaded, when `random_int()` is not available by default.

[wp-includes/random_compat/random.php lines 212-214](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.9.8/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php#L212) are

```
if (!function_exists('random_int')) {
    require_once $RandomCompatDIR.'/random_int.php';
}
```

- So if your server is PHP7 and PHP's own `random_int()` is callable, this one is used and the file never included.
- If your server is not PHP7 or PHP's own `random_int()` is not callable for any reasons, the file is included and another implementation will be given.

This is done, so WordPress can run on different systems. Those with PHP5 and those with PHP7.

How is it different? I can't really speak to it. The files WP uses seem to be from [this `random_compat` repository](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat), which is also linked from the PHP doc (and suggested if you don't have PHP's own implementation available).

One quick difference that I already saw: PHP's `random_int()` tries to use [`getrandom(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) on Linux machines, while the compat `random_int()` only uses `/dev/urandom`.

When in doubt, I would use the system's versions (PHP) instead of those introduced by software (WP). But that is only my opinion.

Comment: "When in doubt, I would use the system's versions" It sounds like you explain at the start of your answer that you can't choose. Either it's already in there (PHP >= 7) and WP won't load it, or it's not there so WP will load it. Is there a middle ground where you pick yourself (disabling WP's function explicitly, I presume)? Sure, you can make any modification you want. But is it worth it to go non-standard in what seems like a relatively core function?

Comment: @Mast There's always a way. You could load that repository and simply change the function names (`random_int_custom()` eg) for it to be usable. The last comment was rather meant as a: it makes sense that it works this way (rather using system functions than your own), and I wouldn't recommend going the extra miles to circumvent this

Comment: You don't recommend going the extra miles, ok. That's all I wanted to know :-)